# Creating a unique list of dictionaries from a list of dictionaries which contains same keys but different values

Tags: python, dictionary

suppose i have been given a list of dictionaries like this :

```
[{"id":1, "symbol":'A', "num":4}, {"id":2, "symbol":'A', "num":3}, {"id":1, "symbol":'A', "num":5}, {"id":2, "symbol":'B', "num":1}]
```

Now, i have to create a dictionary or alter the current one such that (id, symbol) together are unique and the num value is the sum of all the values present in the dict with that (id,symbol) so that the new dict or the current dict looks something like this:

```
[{"id":1, "symbol":'A', "num":9}, {"id":2, "symbol":'A', "num":3}, {"id":2, "symbol":'B', "num":1}]
```

Comment: Show your effort please? Using code others write for you won't improve your programming skill anyway.

Comment: i am really sorry! i joined today and am not sure what type of questions you can ask? i did try to solve it and am not just asking the solution right away. the approach that i took was to iterate over the list per dict and when i would encounter the same unique key value, i would add that value to my iterative object and delete that dictionary from list thereafter. It's just that my code for this was super buggy so i asked for help. I am really sorry if it goes against the code of conduct of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with plain python.

```
dlst = [{"id":1, "symbol":'A', "num":4}, {"id":2, "symbol":'A', "num":3},
    {"id":1, "symbol":'A', "num":5}, {"id":2, "symbol":'B', "num":1}]


# Create a dict where keys are tuples of (id,symbol), values are num

combined_d = {}

for d in dlst:
    id_sym = (d["id"], d["symbol"])
    if id_sym in combined_d:
        combined_d[id_sym] += d["num"]
    else:
        combined_d[id_sym] = d["num"]

# create a list of dictionaries from the tuple-keyed dict

result = []

for k, v in combined_d.items():
    d = {"id": k[0], "symbol": k[1], "num": v}
    result.append(d)

print(result)
```

It does what you want, but the resulting list is not sorted, as it's built from a dictionary.

Comment: @Nisrag I'm glad I could help, I'm fairly new to python as well, there aren't many questions I can answer, but I find helping others solve their problems to be a great learning experience :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go the `pandas.DataFrame` way -

```
import pandas as pd

a = [{"id":1, "symbol":'A', "num":4}, {"id":2, "symbol":'A', "num":3}, {"id":1, "symbol":'A', "num":5}, {"id":2, "symbol":'B', "num":1}]
b = pd.DataFrame(a)
c = b.groupby(['id', 'symbol'])['num'].sum().reset_index()
print(c)
d = list(c.to_dict(orient='index').values())
print(d)
```

**Output**

```
[{'id': 1, 'symbol': 'A', 'num': 9}, {'id': 2, 'symbol': 'A', 'num': 3}, {'id': 2, 'symbol': 'B', 'num': 1}]
```

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` in the following manner:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

grouper = itemgetter("id", "symbol")
result = []
for key, grp in groupby(sorted(input_data, key = grouper), grouper):
    temp_dict = dict(zip(["id", "symbol"], key))
    temp_dict["num"] = sum(item["num"] for item in grp)
    result.append(temp_dict)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'num': 9, 'symbol': 'A'},
 {'id': 2, 'num': 3, 'symbol': 'A'},
 {'id': 2, 'num': 1, 'symbol': 'B'}]
```